# python regex negative lookahead assertion

Tags: python, regex

I'm a cs newbie and am currently working to get a python regex pattern like this:

```
it must contain "stop (at most 10 words inbetween) mail" and do not contain "mail stop".
```

that is to say,

```
  "please stop the mail, and I want the mail stop" AND "please stop the mail stop" would be rejected. ("mail stop" pattern spotted)


  "please stop the mail" AND "please stop the mail, I want the mail to stop" both would be accepted.(only "stop ~ mail" pattern is seen, and no "mail stop")
```

what I currently have is:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("(?=(stop\s+(\w+\s+){0,10}mail[^\s]*))(?!mail\s+stop)")
print(pattern.search("please stop the mail, I want the mail to stop").group())
```

but somehow it doesn't work the way I want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Eric

Comment: And what part of the input you want to capture to `group()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need the entire input string to be returned in the event of a match

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(".*stop\s+(\w+\s+){0,10}mail(?!(\s+stop|(.*mail stop))).*")
>>> print(pattern.search("please stop the mail, I want the mail to stop"))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x15c43c0>
>>> print(pattern.search("please stop the mail stop"))
None
>>> print(pattern.search("please stop the mail, and I want the mail stop"))
None
```